# How to parse following in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to shell script. Pls help .

```
D0:B3:3F:73:67:DB  -44 dBm / -95 dBm (SNR 51)  1860 ms ago
        RX: 1.0 MBit/s, MCS 0, 20MHz                     901 Pkts.
        TX: 72.2 MBit/s, MCS 7, 20MHz, short GI          602 Pkts.
D0:B3:3F:73:67:DC  -44 dBm / -95 dBm (SNR 52)  1860 ms ago
        RX: 1.0 MBit/s, MCS 0, 20MHz                     901 Pkts.
        TX: 72.2 MBit/s, MCS 7, 20MHz, short GI          602 Pkts.
D0:B3:3F:73:67:DD  -44 dBm / -95 dBm (SNR 53)  1860 ms ago
        RX: 1.0 MBit/s, MCS 0, 20MHz                     901 Pkts.
        TX: 72.2 MBit/s, MCS 7, 20MHz, short GI          602 Pkts.
```

How to parse `D0:B3:3F:73:67:DX` , `SNR`,`RX` ,`Tx` , `MCS' value ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

1. Parse mac addresses:  `grep -o '^[[:alnum:]]\{2\}\(:[[:alnum:]]\{2\}\)\{5\}'`
2. SNR: `grep -o 'SNR [0-9]\{1,\}' | cut -d' ' -f2`
3. MCS: same as SNR (just replace SNR with MCS)
4. RX: `grep -o 'RX: [0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}' | cut -d' ' -f2`
5. TX: same as RX (replace RX with TX)

I would parse into associative arrays: [http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-associative-arrays][1]